# jQuery attr() working for first element only

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't understand why attr() get called for only one time,

my html is

```
<table id="myTable">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>...</td>
            <td>...</td>
            <td>
                <abbr title='first'>Demo1</abbr>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>...</td>
            <td>...</td>
            <td>
                <abbr title='second'>Demo2</abbr>
            </td>
        </tr>
        .
        .
        .
    </tbody>
</table>
```

now I want to get "title" of all `abbr`  so wrote following query

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    console.log($('#myTable tr td:nth-child(3) abbr').attr("title"));
}
```

So, it should return me

```
first
second
.
.
.
```

but output is only `"first"`,

but if write

```
var oRows = $('#myTable tbody tr');
$.each(oRows, function (i) {
    console.log($(this).children('td:nth-child(5)').children().attr("title"));
});
```

then I am getting right output.
but I don't think it is a proper approach, so can any body please tell me where I am going wrong.

Also I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3306414/jquerys-attr-function-works-only-one-time) answer, but still I am not clear

Thank you

Comment: Instead of `:nth-child(3)` I think you need `:eq(3)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.attr()` returns the attribute of the first element. If you want the attributes of all of the matched elements, use `map`:

```
var titles = $('#myTable tr td:eq(3) abbr').map(function() {
    return $(this).attr('title');   // or just `return this.title`
}).get();
```

Comment: I marked a question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38446549/getting-clicked-class-data-attribute?noredirect=1#comment64298580_38446549) as duplicate of this one - albeit that other question refers to the `data()`, rather than `attr()`, method - would you be willing to update your answer to explain that the same is true of the other getter methods, such as `text()`, `data()`, `html()` and so forth? (I'd edit myself but it feels rather too much like co-opting your answer.)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a much simple way. get all abbr elements from table myTable and give their title.

http://jsfiddle.net/cngpd/

```
$("abbr", $("#myTable")).each(function () {
    console.log($(this).attr('title'));
})
```

Answer (score -1):

This way you get it for every element:

JS

```
  $(".ele_title").click(function(){
    var value = $(this).attr('title');
    alert(value);
  });
```

HTML

```
<abbr class='ele_title' title='first'>Demo1</abbr>
<abbr class='ele_title' title='second'>Demo1</abbr>
<abbr class='ele_title' title='third'>Demo1</abbr>
```